# Restore Redux store from Angular app in ReactJS application

Tags: angular, reactjs, redux

I have app where I combine `Angular 7` and `React 16`. I need pass only part of data between `Angular` & `React`, so I create `Redux` `store` for this data.

For Angular part I use `NgRedux` and this part work good.

Now I need access for this `store` from `React` components. Now I have only one idea, to inject `store` into react compnent. This works very well when I doesn't use `NgRedux` and I inject data into `React` component, but now with `NgRedux` I doesn't have any idea how can I access `Redux` `store` from `React` app.

Comment: The simple answer is [`react-redux`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux). But I have to ask, why are you using both Angular and React in a single app?

Comment: I need both of them because I want to use some components form React without rewrite them. Additionally we had a problem with dynamic compnent generation base on XML from API, and all of this components are generated from XML.
And I know how can I create a store with `react-redux` but I doesn't have any idea how can I grab Angular Redux store from react-redux.

Comment: If you can't find any existing tooling that can do the heavy lifting in a framework-agnostic way... remember that redux/flux is mostly just a pattern to follow, you can implement it yourself and there are articles to show you how to do that. The libraries are a convenience, not a necessity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I use now singleton class, and I use this class to keep there ngRedux instance. Do you have any better idea?

```
export class ReduxSingleton {
    private static instance: ReduxSingleton;

    public store;

    constructor() {
        if (ReduxSingleton.instance) {
            return ReduxSingleton.instance;
        }

        ReduxSingleton.instance = this;
    }

    setStore(store) {
        this.store = store;
    }
}
```